# Five characters in search of an exit

Tags: the-twilight-zone

The story titled 'Five characters in search of an exit' was based on a short story called 'The Depository' by Marvin Petal. I was curious if anyone has read Petal's story and knows what book it might be in. I've searched online but can't find any info on it. Thanks

Comment: Some references refer to it as 'unpublished'.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "The title is a variation on the Pirandello play [Six Characters in Search of an Author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Characters_in_Search_of_an_Author) and Jean-Paul Sartre's [No Exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Exit)." I don't know if they took any of the plot as well, but it might be worth checking those out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this may not be the most enjoyable answer to see, but from what I've been able to see the story went unpublished, and Petal gave the rights for his story to writer Rod Sterling.[(1)](http://twilightzonevortex.blogspot.com/2016/09/five-characters-in-search-of-exit.html) [(2)](http://mylifeintheshadowofthetwilightzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/tz-promo-five-characters-in-search-of.html) [(3)](https://twitter.com/thenightgallery/status/546865538904113152)

This information is not above question, however, as my sources are two blogs made by from what I can tell are super fans and a Tweet made by fan account.